# Issue with Neo4j GDS 1.4.1 K-Spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, neo4j

I'm following Noe4j's online document at https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/minimum-weight-spanning-tree/ , it seems that the Cypher to query K-Spanning tree doesn't work:

```
MATCH (n:Place)
WITH n.id AS Place, n.kminst AS Partition, count(*) AS count
WHERE count = 3
RETURN Place, Partition
```

Should it be modifyed to the following?

```
MATCH (n:Place)
WITH n.kminst AS Partition, count(*) AS count
WHERE count = 3
MATCH (n:Place)
WHERE n.kminst=Partition
RETURN n
```

I'v downloaded the example transport data of the book <[Graph Algorithms](https://neo4j.com/graph-algorithms-book/)> from https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920233145/tree/master/data, and loaded it into a graph database, all path algorithms of the package is O.K. except the K-Spanning tree, can't figure out how to make it work.

```
MATCH (source:Place {id: "Amsterdam"})
CALL gds.alpha.spanningTree.kmin.write({
     nodeProjection:'Place',
     relationshipProjection:{
     EROAD:{
         type:'EROAD',
         properties:'distance',
         orientation:'NATURAL'
     }},
     startNodeId:id(source),
     relationshipWeightProperty:'distance',
     writeProperty: 'kminst',
     k: 3
})
YIELD createMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount
RETURN createMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount

MATCH (n:Place)
WITH n.kminst AS partition, count(*) AS count
RETURN partition, count
```

There's no partition gets the value 3, so don't know how to extract the result with a Cypher like this:

```
MATCH (n:Place)
WITH n.kminst AS Partition, count(*) AS count
WHERE count = 3
MATCH (n:Place)
WHERE n.kminst=Partition
RETURN n
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

O.K., get the key that the Prim algorithm only applies to UNDIRECTED graph, should be mentioned in [the algorithm document](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/alpha-algorithms/minimum-weight-spanning-tree/#alpha-algorithms-minimum-weight-spanning-tree).
Read the source of Prim algorithm at https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science/blob/master/alpha/alpha-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/spanningTrees/Prim.java .